# SD-card isn't visible to boot from

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, sd-card

I've created a bootable flash SD-card. However, on boot it's not visible in the list of "Boot from". When I use a flash-usb stick, it's visible and I'm able to boot from it.

What can be an issue?

Comment: Your BIOS maybe ?? Are you sure that slot you put the SD card in is designated to be bootable device according to your BIOS ?

Comment: Your bios is configured for boot via EFI or with legacy mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are plugging your SD card into a card reader
that is built into your computer. If so, it could quite simply be that
your computer does not support booting from SD.

You could try putting your SD card in a USB card reader, and boot from
that. As that should appear to your computer just like any other USB
drive, booting should work.